# iOS UISwitch keep sending message every 4 second

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I have a chatting app that has a uiswitch. If the Switch button is on, I want the app to send "hi" continuously every 3 seconds even the app is in background mode. I know that I can use NSTimer, but I don't really know how to implement that in this code(This is my first time to develop iOS app). Please help me with this.

My code is :

```
// Allocate, initialize, and add the automatic button.
_AutomaticSend = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([self width] - 50.0, textAreaY + Center(160.0, textAreaHeight), 50.0, 50.0)];
[_AutomaticSend addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and

```
// Switch action
//NSUInteger counter = 0;

- (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

    if([sender isOn]){
        for (int a=1; a<=300; a++)
        {
            //[self performSelector:@selector(changeSwitch:) withObject:_textField afterDelay:70.0];
            [sender setOn:YES animated:YES];
            [_textField setText:@"hi"];
            NSString * text = [_textField text];

            // Update status.

            [[TSNAppContext singleton] updateStatus:text];

            // Add the status to the bubble.
            [self appendLocalPeerTableViewCellWithMessage:text];

        }


       // NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
    } else{
        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
    }

}
```

Now, the app is showing all "hi" after all 300 "hi" is ready to show. But I want it to send it one by one continuously.

Comment: call your function every 3 second than you get message in every 3 second

Comment: Is there any way to automatically call my function every 3 second?

Comment: use `NStimer` call your method every 4 sec

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a `NSTimer` instance and a counter in your view controller:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger counter;
   ```
2. Implement the method when timer is fired:

   ```
   - (void)timerAction:(id)sender {
       [_textField setText:@"hi"];
       NSString * text = [_textField text];

       // Update status.

       [[TSNAppContext singleton] updateStatus:text];

       // Add the status to the bubble.
       [self appendLocalPeerTableViewCellWithMessage:text];

       // stop the timer after sending for 300 times
       self.counter += 1;
       if (self.counter >= 300) {
           [self.timer invalidate];
           self.timer = nil;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Starts the timer when switch is on:

   ```
   - (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{
       if ([sender isOn]) {
           self.counter = 0;
           self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
       } else {
           // kill the timer when switch is off
           [self.timer invalidate];
           self.timer = nil;
       }
   }
   ```

However, you can't make the timer to continue working indefinitely after your app is entering background (with some exceptions: VoIP, GPS applications, etc.).  Please refer to the official document [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTimer`: [Documentation of NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/)

Declare property of `NSTimer` in `.h` file:

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSTimer *myTimer;

- (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender
{
   if([sender isOn]){
   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 4 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(AddMessage:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

   } else{
    [self.timer invalidate];
   }
}
```

After each 4 second, timer will call the below function:

```
-(void) AddMessage:(NSTimer*) timer 
{ 
    //Add Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Nstimer *timer in .h
```

In your UISwitch Method Write like this

```
- (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

 if([sender isOn]){
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
 target:self
 selector:@selector(targetMethod)
 userInfo:nil
 repeats:NO];
 }
else
{
    [timer invalidate];
}
}
```

targetMethod Like this

```
-(void)targetMethod
 {
[sender setOn:YES animated:YES];
[_textField setText:@"hi"];
NSString * text = [_textField text];

// Update status.

[[TSNAppContext singleton] updateStatus:text];

// Add the status to the bubble.
[self appendLocalPeerTableViewCellWithMessage:text];
```

}